# Divide a dataframe by another dataframe according to index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to divide rows of a dataframe by the same index row in another dataframe. There are the same amount of columns in each dataframe.

The goal is to divide a list of columns by another list of columns.
Is there a way to do this in Pandas?

Here is a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = {"a":[10.,20.,30.,40.,50.],
         "b":[900.,800.,700.,600.,500.],
         "c":[2.,4.,6.,8.,10.]}
data2 = {"f":[1.,2.,3.,4.],
         "g":[900.,800.,700.,600.],
         "h":[10.,20.,30.,40.]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Expected output:

```
    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

As of now, I am using this little function I wrote:

```
def divDF(df1, df2):
    nRow, nCol = df1.shape
    result = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((nRow, nCol)), index=df1.index)
    for col in range(nCol):
        result.iloc[:,col] = df1.iloc[:,col] / df2.iloc[:,col]
    return result
```

Is this the only way or is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas does intrinsic data alignment, so if you label your row index and column the same in both datafames, Pandas will perform the operation as expected.

You need rename your columns to a common name with dictionary mapping old column name to new name as follows:

```
rn_df1 = dict(list(zip(df1.columns.values,(df1.columns+'/'+df2.columns))))
rn_df2 = dict(list(zip(df2.columns.values,(df1.columns+'/'+df2.columns))))
df1.rename(columns=rn_df1).div(df2.rename(columns=rn_df2))
```

output:

```
    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
```

Answer (score 7):

divide by values to get around index alignment

```
dfd = df1.div(df2.values)
dfd.columns = df1.columns + '/' + df2.columns

dfd

    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
```

Or

```
c = df1.columns + '/' + df2.columns
pd.DataFrame(df1.values / df2.values, df1.index, c)

    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
```

---

rebirth of @ScottBoston's answer

```
c = df1.columns + '/' + df2.columns
d1 = dict(zip(df1.columns, c))
d2 = dict(zip(df2.columns, c))
df1.rename(columns=d1) / df2.rename(columns=d2)

    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Sometimes, I simply over think some solutions. Nice piRSquared.

Comment: @ScottBoston believe me... so.. do.. I!

Comment: Updated the sample data. Will this work with different amount of indexes?

Comment: @Oligg so you want to align on index... but align on position for columns?

Comment: I want it to divide an index in df1 by the same index in df2 (if missing then NaN)

Comment: @ScottBoston considering OP's comments... maybe you didn't overthink it.  Undelete and you've got my upvote.

Comment: @piRSquared If we don't need the column names, here is a one liner: df1.div(df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns,df1.columns)))). You can add it to your solution. Thanks :)

Comment: `zip(df1, c)` will suffice if you want to save a few characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) to force index alignment:

```
df3 = np.divide(*df1.align(df2, axis=0))
df3.columns = df1.columns + '/' + df2.columns
```

The resulting output:

```
    a/f  b/g  c/h
0  10.0  1.0  0.2
1  10.0  1.0  0.2
2  10.0  1.0  0.2
3  10.0  1.0  0.2
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: That is really smart use of `align`

Comment: This method seems to be slower on a bigger dataframe (tested with 20k rows, 1k columns) but faster on small dataframe