# Perform Arithmetic operation with two dataframes in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried performing arithmetic operation on a single set of data and it worked, but when i have two separate data frame it is not working. Please guide me.

I want to create a new data frame using the two data frame in question. what i am doing is plain division.  As an example i have provided the two data frame and the resulting data frame

DF1[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31UHQ.png)

DF2[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2PJP.png)

Resulting table has the percentage arrived from dividing the values in the two data frame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqilf.png)

Comment: Since your rows are different, you can try iterating over the rows and create a new resultant dataframe. Try using iterrows.

Comment: still not working

Comment: This post might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466121/divide-a-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-according-to-index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divide a dataframe by another dataframe according to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466121/divide-a-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-according-to-index)